# Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #1 error

Tags: aapt2

I am new to java and android.
I am trying to build an android browser using android studio on win 7.
The following error shows when trying to build my app:

Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\borinquenatl\AndroidStudioProjects\BrowserExample\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:34: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: C:\Users\borinquenatl.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\aa884e337f256396fb379397162453be\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\borinquenatl\AndroidStudioProjects\BrowserExample\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\borinquenatl\AndroidStudioProjects\BrowserExample\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
**Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #1**

**My activity_main.xml file is :**

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/editTextLink"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/btn_view"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

</ LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/my_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </WebView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. There was a space between the   </  and Linear Layout tag.

Answer (score -2):

Android resource compilation failed
Output:

> D:\WorkSpace\BaiduMap\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:0:
>   error: xml parser error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command:

> C:\Users\wanji.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\7b5ed62a00ce7ca907cc09010179021e\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
>   compile --legacy \
>           -o \
>           D:\WorkSpace\BaiduMap\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
>           D:\WorkSpace\BaiduMap\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
>   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #1